# Как выводить посты в цикле с -1?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый, подскажите как сделать смещение на один пост, получается за минусом одного поста, те что бы последний добавленный пост в данной рубрике не выводился.

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query('cat=9&showposts=5');
        if( $query->have_posts() ){
            while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <h2>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } 
     else echo 'Записей нет.';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос надо написать так:

```
$query = new WP_Query('cat=9&showposts=5&offset=1');
```